# xmlReader won't quit reading large file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlreader

I'm trying to read a big XML file (~400 Mb) and here's my code -

```
    $reader = new \XMLReader();
    $reader->open( 'big-ass-xml-file.xml');
    while($reader->read()) {
        if($reader->nodeType == \XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'APPLICATION' ) {
            $application = new \SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXml
            $my_array[] = [$application->title->__toString()];
        }
    }
    $reader->close();
```

The problem is that the reader won't quit after reading the file. It'd just continue reading the file all over.

I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue. Would really appreciate if someone could offer a helping hand.

Update: Adding sample job feed -

```
<Jobs>
   <APPLICATION>
      <TITLE>This is a title</TITLE>
      <SUMMARY>Summary of the application</SUMMARY>
      ....
   </APPLICATION>
   <APPLICATION>
      <TITLE>Another Title</TITLE>
      <SUMMARY>Another summary</SUMMARY>
   </APPLICATION>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *it won't quit after reading the file*? Does it keep printing output?

Comment: Yes, it does. Basically goes into infinite loop.

Comment: This code is invalid (and therefore clearly not the actual code that gave you the problem); this line is missing something: `$application = new \SimpleXMLElement($reader->readOuterXml`